# Why is resteasy.providers still required when using Spring with @Provider annotations?

Tags: java, spring, jax-rs, web.xml, resteasy

I have a Resteasy application that uses Spring and contains `ContainerRequestFilter` and `ContainerResponseFilter` implementations annotated with `@Provider`.  The application is using version `3.0-beta-6` of Resteasy.

These filters work as expected when they are added to the `resteasy.providers` context parameter in web.xml like so:

```
<context-param>
      <param-name>resteasy.providers</param-name>
      <param-value>foo.filter.LoggingRequestFilter,
                   foo.filter.LoggingResponseFilter</paramvalue>
</context-param>
```

If I remove the filters from here they are no longer called.

I was assuming that these providers would automatically register with Resteasy when using `org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.spring.SpringContextLoaderListener`.  The strange thing to me is that it worked for `PreProcessInterceptor` implementations in previous versions of Resteasy, and still works in v3, but Filters and ExceptionMappers do not auto-register.

### Questions

1. Why is the `resteasy.providers` context parameter necessary if the classes are annotated with `@Provider` and scanned by Spring?
2. Is there a programmatic way to set these providers at runtime?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In order to get the providers scanned by Spring I had to add the `includeFilters` parameter to `@ComponentScan` on my Spring Java configuration class.

```
@ComponentScan(value = "com.foo", 
               includeFilters = @ComponentScan.Filter(type = FilterType.ANNOTATION, value = Provider.class))
```

You can also just annotate them with `@Component` along with `@Provider` and Spring will make sure they get detected by Resteasy when using Resteasy's `SpringContextLoaderListener`.